# seperable differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

b)  $(2xy^3)dx + (3x2y^2 + y^4)dy = 0$

c)  $(2xy^3)dx + (3x2y^2 + y^2)dy = 0$

I know that $c$ is a separable differential equation but $b$ is not.  Why?  The only difference is the power of the final $y$.

Comment: could you please write this in Latex? it's kind of hard to see what's going on.

Comment: c factors but b doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

c)  $(2xy^3)dx + (3x^2y^2 + y^2)dy = 0$

$$\frac{2x}{3x^2+1}dx =-\frac{1}{y}dy $$
All $x$ are on the left, all $y$ on the right. So, the differential equation is separable.

$\:$

b)  $(2xy^3)dx + (3x^2y^2 + y^4)dy = 0$

$$(2x)dx = -(\frac{3x^2}{y} + y)dy $$

The therm at right is not function of $y$ only ( $x^2$ is remaining in it ). So, the differential equation is not separable.